# JQuery .post function dataType parameter seems not to do anything

Tags: jquery

Using JQuery version 1.4.4, I am unable to get a proper JSON output when I call .ajax or .post like the following:

```
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: callbackUri, data: { cow: ["oh", "hello", "there"]}, success: returnFunction, dataType: "json"});
```

or the following:

```
$.post(callbackUri, { cow: ["oh", "hello", "there"]}, returnFunction, "json");.
```

The body of the HTTP request looks like this in both cases:

```
cow%5B%5D=oh&cow%5B%5D=hello&cow%5B%5D=there
```

It's probably a very simple configuration issue. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment "The body of the HTTP request ... " you may be misunderstanding what the JSON option does. It specifies the type of data the request is expecting back from the server -- it has NOTHING to do with the format the data is sent to the server.

The body of the HTTP request is going to be the same in all cases, unless you create a json string and send it as a value.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the data being sent to the server (HTTP request body).

The `dataType` parameter is what type the return value from the server should be.  'json' means that jQuery will auto-parse the response as JSON.

Check the response from your server, it may not be valid JSON.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I misunderstood the documentation when it said "type of data expected from the server". I now pass in JSON.stringify(data) and it works fine.